# Codefolding IF|FOREACH for textmate

Tags: textmate, textmatebundles

Hope someone can help.

I am a new user to textmate and want to add code folding to if|endif & foreach|endforeach on textmate.

These are the current supported folds

```
foldingStartMarker = '(/\*|\{\s*$|<<<HTML)';
foldingStopMarker = '(\*/|^\s*\}|^HTML)';
```

I have tried

```
foldingStartMarker = '(/\*|\{\s*$|<<<HTML|if)';
foldingStopMarker = '(\*/|^\s*\}|^HTML|endif)';
```

Which starts the fold for an if but the stop Marker is not being picked up.

Has anyone else done this ?

Hope you can advise

Comment: I'm certain you want to add this codefolding to a certain programming language, because I can fold any loop or if-statement in a Ruby program. So which language do you target?

Comment: php if & endif also maybe foreach & endforeach

Answer (score 0):

Change The HTML bundle instead of the PHP bundle!

I've changed `|array\s?(\s*$` into `|array(\s*$` to get array folding. This might work for you as well.

I've also tried this: `|array\s*(\s*$` because I want to fold **array(** as well as **array (** or **array    (**. I don't know if this is exactly the right syntax, but it works perfectly!

Thanks to Chris Adams:
http://old.nabble.com/Any-chance-of-a-little-help-sorting-this-language-regexp-to-make-php-coding-less-painful-in-textmate--td30458020.html